# How old do I have to be to take a loan, and how should I go about the process?

Tags: united-states, loans, minor

I'm currently 16 and have been invited to attend a National Youth Conference for National Security in Washington DC this upcoming fall. I just moved in with my mom and this trip isn't exactly ideal for us financially. My mom said I was more than welcome to go on the trip as long as I came up with the money. I could make the money over the summer but the enrollment deadline is June 24. I've made a Go Fund Me page but I don't think that will help in time. I'm not sure how old I must be to take out a loan or anything about the process. Any help/advice is appreciated in this situation

Comment: Just as a sanity check: a lot of these conferences make a fair bit of money of the students and are happy to invite anyone who is willing to pay. I recommend triple checking the credentials. See for example http://blog.prepscholar.com/national-youth-leadership-forum

Comment: I'd suggest checking with your local young dems or young republicans, whichever is more affiliated with the conference. In this case, probably the young republicans would be your best bet. A lot of times such organizations will sponsor local delegations to go to national political conferences or will help you raise money to go.

Answer (score 13):

To explain *why* you have to be 18: If you are not 18, then any contract that you sign can be voided (made invalid) by either you or your parents. So it would be completely legal for you to go to the bank, ask for a $1000 loan, and for the bank to give you the loan. But then you could spend the money, and tell the bank "sorry, I changed my mind, I don't want that loan, and sorry again, but the money is gone". At that point, there would be nothing the bank could do to get their money back.

Obviously, banks don't like this, so they won't lend you money.

Answer (score 11):

At your age, the only place you are going to get a loan is from relatives. If you can't... Go to next year's conference. Missing it this year might feel like a disaster, but it really, really isn't.

Comment: Ouch... But so true

Answer (score 4):

In general, you would have to be the age of majority (generally, 18) to take out a loan. Additionally, your credit rating must be sufficient for the bank or loan company to be comfortable loaning you money.